# WebLogic is changing state automatically

Tags: eclipse, debugging, weblogic9.x

I am facing a weired problem, I have configured WebLogic 9.2 with Eclipse Helios. I have started the server in debug mode, It works fine in debug mode, however after a while it changes its state to "started" or "stopped". It is behaving weirdly.

I have re-installed and re configured WebLogic and its domain, used a new Workspace. However the problem persists.

Any suggestions please.

Regards,
Sarbbottam

Comment: I also see, "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453" getting printed in the console when the state of the server getting changed.

Comment: Post more information from the console.

Comment: do you want the complete console log????

Comment: <May 3, 2011 2:36:46 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING> 
<May 3, 2011 2:36:47 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode> 
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this issue started suddenly after installing [launchy](http://www.launchy.net/). I have not uninstall-ed launchy but just exited it process. The issue seems to be resolved. Really crazy and weired.

Regards,
Sarbbottam